# Two ObservableCollections for DataGrid possible?. One for Rows, second for the DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

Trying find a way to handle two ObservableCollections for DataGrid. One ObservableCollection should hold collection of DataGrids, another - collection of Rows of concrete DataGrid.
On buttonclick I add Tabs which contain TextBoxes and DataGrid. I enter data into DataGrid directly. On adding new Tab I want to save the Datagrid in this Tab and want to have fresh (with no data) DataGrid on new Tab and when I change Tabs I want to see my entered data in each concrete Tab DataGrid. Is this poыsible?

```
ObservableCollection<DataGridsOBC>[0]
DataGrid 1
+---------------------------------------------+
+        |  Column 1  |  Column 2 |  Column 3 |
+        |  bind to   |  bind to  |  bind to  |
+        |  Property 1| Property 2| Property 3|
+---------------------------------------------|
           ObservableCollection<RowsOBC>
+ Row 0  | ObservableCollection<RowsOBC>[0]   |
+ Row 1  | ObservableCollection<RowsOBC>[1]   |
+ Row 2  | ObservableCollection<RowsOBC>[2]   |
+  ...   | ObservableCollection<RowsOBC>[...] |
+---------------------------------------------+
ObservableCollection<DataGridsOBC>[1]
DataGrid 2
+---------------------------------------------+
+        |  Column 1  |  Column 2 |  Column 3 |
+        |  bind to   |  bind to  |  bind to  |
+        |  Property 1| Property 2| Property 3|
+---------------------------------------------|
           ObservableCollection<RowsOBC>
+ Row 0  | ObservableCollection<RowsOBC>[0]   |
+ Row 1  | ObservableCollection<RowsOBC>[1]   |
+ Row 2  | ObservableCollection<RowsOBC>[2]   |
+  ...   | ObservableCollection<RowsOBC>[...] |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

How this should look in xaml if its posible?

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding }">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" Binding="{Binding Property 1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" Binding="{Binding Property 2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 3" Binding="{Binding Property 3, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid
```

And in code behind?

```
 public class DataGridsOBCViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    public ObservableCollection<RowsOBC> _Rows;
    public ObservableCollection<RowsOBC> Rows
    {
        get { return _Rows != null ? _Rows : _Rows = new ObservableCollection<RowsOBC>(); }
        set { _Rows = value; OnPropChange("Rows"); }
    }

public DataGridsOBCViewModel()
    {

    }

}

public class RowsOBC : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Properties> _Items;
    public ObservableCollection<Properties> Items
    {
        get { return _Items != null ? _Properties : _Items = new ObservableCollection<Properties>(); }
        set { _Items = value; OnPropChange("Properties"); }
    }
}

public class Properties: ViewModelBase
{
    private string _Property1;
    private string _Property2;
    private string _Property3;

    public string Property1
    {
        get { return _Property1; }
        set { if (_Property1 != value) { _Property1 = value; OnPropChange("Property1"); } }
    }

    //............... etc
}
```

Comment: `ObservableCollection`s should *not* hold UI elements. Instead, they should hold the *data* that is to be data bound to the UI elements and those UI elements should be defined in `DataTemplate`s.

Comment: So I should do something like: <DataGrid.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>....</DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.ItemTemplate>?

Comment: I'd define it in `Resources`, but yes. In your `DataTemplate`, you should have some collection control (I think you said a `DataGrid`) that data binds to the inner collection items. Therefore, each of your outer data items should have a collection to populate the inner items with.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but still my datagrid's data doesnt refresh upon adding new Tabs. It just copies data from the first one...